# How to make a <div> occupy the full height of <td>

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.full {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 10px solid red;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#content>table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#content>table>tbody>tr>td {
  border: 10px solid blue;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="height: 100%">
        <div id="container">
          <div class="full">
            foo
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
  </table>
</div>
```

What I want is to have the div of the second td strech vertically up to the height of the enclosing td, in order for the fieldsets of the two cells to appear equally tall. I want the red fieldset to appear as tall as the blue one.

It works in Chrome, not in Firefox!?!?
I don't care that the borders go outside. The borders are there only to show the div (black) is not expanding to 100% even though the cell/td (blue) is.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Since you tagged css3, use flexbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1.) Add ´box-sizing: border-box;´as a general rule (* selector) (if you want to see the red border on all four sides of the cell)

2.) Add `padding: 0` to the cell to get rid of the tiny white space between red and blue borders.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.full {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 10px solid red;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#content>table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#content>table>tbody>tr>td {
  border: 10px solid blue;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="height: 100%">
        <div id="container">
          <div class="full">
            foo
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
  </table>
</div>
```